# How to install Rmpfr in R 3.1.1

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am using **R 3.1.1** with **Ubuntu 13.10**. When I am trying to install **Rmpfr** package, I am getting error

```
package ‘Rmpfr’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Can someone tell me how to install it?

Comment: First, which command did you use?

Comment: install.packages("Rmpfr",dep=T)

Comment: It works for me. Problem with the mirror you choose? Did you try with another one?

Comment: which mirror are you using

Comment: cran.at.r-project.org

Comment: still getting the same error, are you using R 3.1.1 only?

Comment: Warning: unable to access index for repository cran.at.r-project.org/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘Rmpfr’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Comment: thanks man, with other mirror it worked